# Using internal Microsoft editors in custom workflow activities

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I am creating custom activity using Workflow 4.0 and i would like to use existing Microsoft property editor. To be precise i'd like to use SendContentPropertyEditor. This class is internal but i was hoping that i will be able to use it using following code:

```
[Editor("System.ServiceModel.Activities.Presentation.SendContentPropertyEditor, System.Activities.Core.Presentation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35", typeof(DialogPropertyValueEditor))]
[DefaultValue(null)]
public SendContent SendContent { get; set; }
```

The problem is when I try to set value to this property in property grid I get NullPointerException. You can see stacktrace on screenshot below:

[image]

Have you any ideas how to resolve this issue so that it will be possible to use that editor?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a wrapper DialogPropertyValueEditor that uses reflection.